# Show that the bilinear form is well-defined

Tags: bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$, $\langle-.-\rangle$ a symmetric bilinear form on $V$ and $T \subseteq V$ with

$T :=$ {$v \in V$ | $\langle v, u\rangle = 0$ $\forall v \in V  $}.

I have to show that there exists a bilinearform $\langle-.-\rangle'$ on the quotient space $V/T$ such that

$$\langle v,u \rangle = \langle [v], [u]\rangle'.$$

I already showed the linearity in both components and the symmetry, but I still haven't figured out how to show the well-definedness of the bilinear form. I know that I have to proof that

$[v] = [v']$ ^ $[u] = [u']$ $=>$ $\langle [v'],[u']\rangle'$ = $\langle [v],[u]\rangle',$

but I wasn't able to manage it yet. Does someone have a clear hint for me?

[image]

Comment: Write up what it means for two vectors to be equal in the quotient and use the definition of $T$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited a picture of my conclusions in the main post. Is this the direction you want me to push in?

Comment: That is a good start. It may be a bit easier to write the condition as $v = v' + t$ for some $t\in T$ though, as this will be easier to work with when looking at the bilinear form.

Comment: Thank you! I'll think a while about that and comment later on. :-)

Comment: So, I uploaded a complete proof - not sure what to think about it though. Might be too easy. What do you think about it? :-)

Comment: Your conclusion that $\langle v,w\rangle = 0$ is not correct.

Comment: Sigh. :( I've spent a few days thinking about this task, and to be honest: the solution is due by tomorrow. I simply don't see how to prove this. I'd be deeply gratueful if you could tell me the steps I need (if it isn't too much to ask) such that I could at least write the correct solution down and understand it.

Comment: So what is $\langle v + t, u + s\rangle$ when $s,t\in T$? Write it out in full using bilinearity and symmetry of the form.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I was allowed to use bilinearity and symmetry already. I thought I had to show that the form is well-defined before using those properties. :D

Comment: You need to use that the original form has those properties to show that the new one is well-defined.

Comment: Okay, I focussed on the important parts. I guess that's true, but the last conclusion might be too short?

Comment: You need to spell out how you get the equality there (as in how the other terms vanish).

Comment: Yeah, I did that of course, just cut it out so it's easier to read. :)

Comment: I assume the proof is correct then?